# use 2 different namespaces in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this source XML, that is using 2 namespaces.

```
<SyncAssetMaster xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" languageCode="en-US" releaseID="9.2" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" versionID="2.8.0">
    <ApplicationArea>
        <CreationDateTime>2017-06-29T12:06:03Z</CreationDateTime>
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <AssetMaster>
            <UserArea>
                <D xmlns="http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" n="380">SVP245</D>
                <D xmlns="http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" n="383">SVP245 v1</D>
            </UserArea>
        </AssetMaster>
    </DataArea>
</SyncAssetMaster>
```

The D elements have a different namespace, which I declare in the XSLT, as seen from other similar examples online:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:nsWS="http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />   

    <xsl:template match="//my:SyncAssetMaster"> 
        <DataArea>
            <CreationDateTime><xsl:value-of select="//my:CreationDateTime"/></CreationDateTime>
            <ExtensionDate1><xsl:value-of select="//nsWS:UserArea/nsWS:D[@n='380']"/></ExtensionDate1>
        </DataArea>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the required output. The ExtensionDate1 does not appear. Surely it's something simple, I appreciate any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataArea xmlns:nsWS="http://schemas.datastream.net/MP_functions/MP0118_GetGridHeaderData_001_Result" xmlns:my="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
    <CreationDateTime>2017-06-29T12:06:03Z</CreationDateTime>
    <ExtensionDate1>SVP245</ExtensionDate1>
</DataArea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserArea` element is in the namespace you have bound to the prefix `my` so where you want to select it you need to use `my:UserArea` and not `nsWS:UserArea` as you have tried.